# Scanf with a specific format

Tags: c, scanf

I would like to allow the user to only put input in a specific format.
The format:
`a=1,b=-2,c=3` for example. Spaces are allowed inbetween the commas and the characters.
I'm using: `if (scanf("a=%lf,b=%lf,c=%lf",&a,&b,&c) == 1)` but for some reason it doesn't work. How can I fix it?

Comment: `"a=%lf , b=%lf , c=%lf"` Allowing for white-sapce characters means your format string must have them.

Comment: Your condition is also wrong, I wager. `scanf` returns how many items from the format specifiers it read successfully. So to check for success, you'd need to check it returns `3`.

Comment: Deja vous - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40572652/find-numbers-a-b-c-if-it-is-given-ab-bc-and-ac#comment68380903_40572652

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are converting 3 numbers, the return value should be 3 if all conversions are successful. Also note that `%lf` ignores spaces *before* the number.  If you also want to ignore spaces around the `,` and before the `=` or the `a`, add a space in the format string:

```
double a, b, c;

if (scanf(" a =%lf , b =%lf , c =%lf", &a, &b, &c) == 3) {
    /* conversion was successful, 3 numbers parsed */
    ...
}
```

Note however that `scanf()` will not ignore just space characters, it will ignore and whitespace characters, including newlines, tabs, etc.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation on scanf

#### Return value

If successful, the total number of characters written is returned, otherwise a negative number is returned.

Try

```
if (scanf("a=%lf , b=%lf , c=%lf",&a,&b,&c)==3)
```

You must include empty spaces in the string scanf takes as an argument, specifying the format.